# Will aws Cognito count every getid call made for unauthenticated users as a MAU?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

AWS  Cognito doco states that its pointless to store the ID that will generated for an access request by an Unauthenticated user. Their pricing states that charges are based on Monthly Active users i.e active identities received via credentialsProvider.getIdentityId() call.

So I were to implement it in an app or website, and the user either closes the app or website and revisit at a later point that a new ID would be generated and assigned . And that count will be added to the total MAU count?

For ex: if the same user opens/closes the app/website 200 times a day.Will it incur 200 MAUs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Federating with Cognito identity is free, so you will not be charged for the unauthenticated use case you mentioned above. See the last line of Cognito Identity section of the Cognito pricing [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/).

If you are using Cognito user pools, which enables you to create your own directory and allows to manage the username and password based login of your user, you will be charged based on MAUs. No matter how many times the same user logs in/opens or closes the app in a given calendar month, it will be counted as a one MAU.

Comment: Thanks! Found a similar question that seems to be answered on a different site. http://serverfault.com/questions/698650/is-it-free-to-use-amazon-cognito-to-authenticate-users

Comment: very clear answer! "No matter how many times the same user logs in/opens or closes the app in a given calendar month, it will be counted as a one MAU."